# html / css positioning images

Tags: html, css

im looking to position my image in the middle of the screen, maybe a little bit to the left or right, but am looking for help on how to position the image to wherever I feel, also correct my html / css if you believe I am making it too hard / incorrect - many thanks in advance - Miles

Edit: for those wondering what this page is, it's an entrance page with a background image and another image that says "enter here" which is hyperlinked to the index of my actual website.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Enter</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>

<body background="index1background.jpg">

<div id="enterhere">
<p><a href="index2.html" title="Enter Here"><img src="index1enter.png"
    alt="Enter Here"</a></p> 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
#enterhere {
position: middle;
}
```

Comment: Check this http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: There is no `position: middle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
}
```

Then you can add `padding` in order to adjust left and right. The `text-align: center` does not work in this case.

Edit: If you want to go even shorter, here's a shorter version.

```
margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
```

This snippet includes a `margin-top` of `100px`. Here's how it works. Instead of using the keywords `margin-top`, `margin-right`, etc, we use the main keyword, just `margin`. Then the positions:

```
margin: [top] [right] [bottom] [left];
```

This works for the `padding` aswell.

Comment: if I use "img" will it not also try and use my background too?

Comment: and how do I move it from the top downwards a bit?

Comment: negative bottom margin.

Comment: By using "marign-top" you can move it up and down.

Comment: Your background is your body, it's not an "img" tag. If you have multiple images, use the "id" or "class".

Comment: ooh I like your short version, makes a lot more sense now and also looks very neet! thank you so much for the messages, its been a great help.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the text-align property used in case to place your image where ever you want

Comment: where do I place the text-align property?

Comment: Welcome to SO, it's better to provide an example to showing how it must be done

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to place the image in the css take a look at the properties "background-size" and "Background-position".

I'd you choose to bring the images into an img tag specify the position with the container above. There are two ways to handle that. Flexbox and css grid (check the w3 website for awesome details). After the positioning with one of these methods you can adjust the position of your image with the property "margin" which you will set in the image's css.

Make sure it has a reason where you will place your images - css or html. Images placed in html should be relevant to the content (like product pictures). Css placed images should be unnecessary for the content (like decoration images).